# Setup QTabBar position

Tags: qt4, tabs, position, qtabbar

If I use QTabWidget i can call setTabPosition to change it to "South" and have tabs appear at the bottom.

Is there a similar behavior for QTabBar?
Currently on Mac the top left and right corners are rounded and the bottom ones are not.
I wish to invert this look and feel - the top corners to be square and the bottom ones to be rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using:

```
this->myTabBar->setShape(QTabBar::RoundedSouth);
```